# Что значит обратимая логическая операция?

Tags: терминология

Что значит "обратимая логическая операция"?

В чем ее преимущество в сравнении с другими? В каких областях применение обратимых логических операций проявляется больше всего?

Comment: Скопировал Ваш заголовок, без изменений задал вопрос Google. Он, оказывается, знает! Или нужно что-то другое? Тогда желательно уточнить сам вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Логические операции, лежащие в основе работы компьютеров, с физической точки зрения являются необратимыми процессами, т.е. они неизбежно сопровождаются ростом энтропии, следовательно, при выполнении этих операций неизбежно происходит рассеяние энергии.

Эта необратимость заключается в том, что при выполнении некоторых операций происходит потеря информации. Например, операция **И**: `x = x & y`. После выполнения этой операции прежнее значение переменной `x` в общем случае не восстановить, информация теряется.

Идея обратимых вычислений: если в качестве элементарных логических операций допускать только обратимые операции, то в принципе можно проводить вычисления вообще без затрат энергии (т.е., проводить вычисления со сколь угодно малыми затратами энергии). Обратимые логические операции действительно существуют. Например, `!x` (отрицание) или `x^y` (искл. или). Последний, вообще говоря, не обратим, см. документ по ссылке ниже.

Есть универсальные обратимые логические операции - "*гейт Тоффоли*": `x = x ^ (y & z)`.

Любое сколь угодно сложное обратимое вычисление можно представить в виде цепочки гейтов Тоффоли. Также обратимые логические гейты описаны [здесь](http://www.rec.vsu.ru/rus/ecourse/quantcomp/sem6.pdf) в разделе 6.3.